# Schengen Business Visa Rejected from Norway Embassy

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, norway, visa-rejections

Part - 1 Rejection

Case 1:

Rejection reason was justification for the purpose and the condition of the intended stay was not provided:

> The applicant has applied for a visa to meet with client. The applicant has informed the he will be conducting training as well as day to day tasks and workshops and similar sessions with the local team whilst in Norway. where training may be exempted from the requirement of a residence permit, engaging in the work related task is not covered under the any of the exemption of the residence permit. All work relating to the realisation of a contract (product development) is not an activity typically performed by a business traveller outside scope of the provision. 'Workshops' and similar discussion forums are therefore not deemed to be covered, as this type of activity is deemed to be part of the product development, where the participants exchange knowledge and information as part of there ordinary task in their home country. Consequently the stated purpose and conditions to the visa application has not been justified and visa cannot be issued.
>
> Based on the attached description of the application's activities in Norway the applicant must apply for the residence permit.

What should I do next? I do not want residence permit and i have to travel through business visa for 22 days.

Case 2:

> The applicant has informed that he will attend workshops or similar session, as well as development projects at leardal offices. Further, hew will engage in "Continued development based on findings the week before". Such activity is deemed to be part of the product development, thus not covered by any of the exemptions form the requirement of a residence permit. Consequently, the stated purpose and conditions of the visa application has not been justified and a visa cannot be issued.
>
> In invitation letter its was mentioned as During his stay in norway Mr XYZ, will attend workshops discussing future software development projects at client location.

What should be change in purpose of visit? I want business visa only.

Part - 2
Here is invitation letter Planning to apply again,Which among these would justifies visit, would like to visit to gather knowledge for the project.
I have not yet applied just asking for opnion which invite should i apply so that i can have more chance of getting visa. please check previous rejection above.

Require business Schengen visa for 22 days

case Inv_1:

> We hereby kindly ask you to issue a 6 months Schengen business visa for Mr. XYZ, aaa, bearer of passport number: aaa, issued by ttt on ddd, expiring on ddd.
>
> Mr. XYZ who is employed by EEEE in since ABC 20XX with the position of Senior Software Engineer will arrive in Norway on ddd (estimated) and departure to HOME, on ddd (estimated).
>
> QQQ is a client of EEEE for the past 4 years and the relationship is continuing to grow. Recently EEEE was awarded with new project from QQQ, which is a “DDD” and Mr. XYZ is invited to QQQ office to gather knowledge about the project and do a detailed discovery of current functionality and the requirements. As this is an App in Training category, it’s important that Mr. XYZ understands the requirements well before going back to HOME starting the development. There are many workshops and discussion sessions planned for understanding the design, receiving knowledge on equipment/manikins and taking guidance from QQQ team.

Case Inv_2

> We hereby kindly ask you to issue a 6 months Schengen business visa for Mr. XYZ, aaa, bearer of passport number: aaa, issued by ttt on ddd, expiring on ddd.
>
> Mr. XYZ who is employed by EEEE in since ABC 20XX with the position of Senior Software Engineer will arrive in Norway on DDD (estimated) and departure to HOME, on DDD (estimated).
>
> During his stay in Norway, Mr. XYZ will attend project initiation meetings and technical training in software development for the DDD project at QQQ Offices.

Which among two case is proper reason which will come under the Business Visa ?? Among 2 case of letter which has higher chance of getting visa ?

Comment: The text I've put in quote markup (yellow box) is a direct quote from the refusal letter, right? If it's not, please revert my edit by clicking the "edited [however long] ago" link and then the "revert" link under the previous version.

Comment: "I do not want residence permit": but to do the things you need to do, you must get a residence permit.  Pay attention to the last sentence in the quotation and to what that document allows you to do rather than to the name of the document.

Answer (score 6):

> Based on the attached description of the application's activities in Norway the applicant must apply for the residence permit.

*What should I do next?*

Apply for the residence permit. You’ve already received the most relevant advise already. I would follow that.

An applicant may have many reasons to believe that the visa they are applying for is the right one, but ultimately its the issuing authority that decides which activities are allowed. The activities you have listed, are not allowed, according to them. So a re-application for the same visa will not help.

They have your refusal on record, and a quick reapplication with an altered description of intended activities may very well be seen as deception.

**Must Read**: [Does your business trip to Norway require a work permit?](https://www.malmadvokatfirma.no/does-your-business-trip-to-norway-require-a-work-permit/)

Comment: No i do not want residence permit, i want the schengen business visa

Comment: It's not a question of what you want but what you need...

Comment: Your only other option is to change your plans to include only activities that are permitted under a business visa. However, then there's the risk that they will deny the visa because they know you want to do the other stuff.

Comment: can you provide the list of activities that comes under the business visa ?

Comment: https://www.crownrelo.com/sites/default/files/relocations-files/business-visitor-faqs/crown-relocations-business-visitos-faq-netherlands.pdf

Comment: @Mihawkthe only way for you to *legally* do those things you are planning on doing in Norway is to get a residence permit.

Comment: @Mihawk: The link in the answer tell you that "Over the years I have received several questions from clients outside of the EU regarding the necessity of a residence permit (the **official name for work permits** in Norway) when the stay in Norway is for a short period of time. Typically the stay will be longer than a week, or two, but **less than 3 months**". So really doesn't be afraid of the strange name **residence permit**

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi indeed, in Canada, short-term visas are called "temporary resident visa" and in EU free-movement law, EU citizens visiting other countries temporarily are exercising a "right of residence" in those countries under Article 6 of the directive.  Furthermore, use of the word "residence" in unexpected contexts is more likely when the word is used to translate a word from another language (such as Norwegian).  It's best to focus on the document's function -- what it authorizes -- rather than its name.

Comment: @Mihawk What issue do you have with a residence permit?

Answer (score 2):

In response to the edit:

> What should be change in purpose of visit? I want business visa only.

You would qualify for a short-term visa for this visit if you could convince the Norwegian authorities that while you are in Norway you will not perform any activities that are considered under Norwegian immigration law to be work.  These include (based on the letters you quote in your question):

- performing work relating to the realization of a contract, which includes product development, and
- participation in workshops (because they are considered to be part of product development), and
- "continued development based on findings" because it is explicitly product development.

Since it seems that you've applied and been rejected twice, however, you may find it difficult to convince the authorities of the credibility of a subsequent visa application with significantly different description of the activities.  Your better bet, therefore, is to apply for a different document, *as you have been advised to do by the Norwegian authorities,* or to conduct your meetings remotely.